# Text/Javascript rowcount is not working returns only 0

Tags: javascript, laravel, rowcount, dd

im using laravel and javascript and the rowcount does not read the following variables after first vairables.  what im trying to do is to submit multiple IPs and when i check it using dd only gets the first variable and in the "alert(rowCount); it returns zero". plss help with this thank you..

this is the blade.php

```
</div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
                <h5 class="text-truncate col-10 mt-3"> <span class="fas fa-list-ol icons"></span> <b>Server Description</b></h5>
                <hr class="col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11"></hr>
                <div class="tbl_div row col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 ">
                    <div class="row col-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" class="p-2" id="addrow"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span> ADD Source / Destination</a>
                    </div>  
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-fw-widget " id="tblItems" >
                        <thead class="">
                            <td class="col-md-1  text-center border-0">
                            <td class="col-md-3 col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 border-0">Source Servername</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3 col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 border-0">IP address</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3 col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 border-0">Destination Servername</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3 col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 border-0">IP address</td>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- @foreach(old('source_name', ['value']) as $fw_ip) -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
                                    <label class="form-label" id="row_no"><b>#1</b></label></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- <label class="form-label">Item</label> -->
                                        <input type="text" name="source_namex[]" class="form-control">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- <label class="form-label">Item</label> -->
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="sourceip[]" maxlength="15" value="{{ old('sourceip.'.$loop->index) }}" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- <label class="form-label">Item</label> -->
                                        <input type="text" name="destname[]" class="form-control" value="{{ old('destname.'.$loop->index) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">
                                        <!-- <label class="form-label">Item</label> -->
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="destip[]" maxlength="15" value="{{ old('destip.'.$loop->index) }}" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-3">
                                        <center><span class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg mt-2 icons removerow"></span></center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <!-- @endforeach -->
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-allcard btn-block col-10">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascipt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
    var rowCount = $("#tblItems tbody>td").length;
    var rowCount = ;
    alert(rowCount);
    $('.type').change(function()
    {
       
    });
    $('#addrow').click(function()
    {
        rowCount += 1;
        
        $("#tblItems tbody>tr:first").clone(true).insertAfter("#tblItems tbody>tr:last");
        $("#tblItems tbody>tr:last").attr("id", "tr"+rowCount);
        $("#tblItems tbody>tr:last #row_no").text("#"+rowCount);
        $("#tblItems tbody>tr:last #row_no").css('font-weight','bold');
        $("#tblItems tbody>tr:last :input").val("");
       
     
    });
    $('.removerow').click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')
        $('table#tblItems tr#'+id).remove();
        rowCount -=1;
    });


      
</script>
```

Comment: What does that `var rowCount = ;` is doing there?

Comment: i was trying the rowcount starts to 1. that's supposed to be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your CSS selector, specifically the `>` in `#tblItems tbody>td"`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the *direct children* of elements matched by the first.

(Emphasis mine)

This means you are instructing jQuery to return all `<td>` elements that are direct children of the `<tbody>` in the the table with id `#tblItems`. But *there are no* such direct children because all of the `<td>` elements are children of a `<tr>`.

Your selector would either need to include the `<tr>` child, as in:

```
$("#tblItems tbody>tr>td")
```

Or just do without the child combinator (>) completely:

```
$("#tblItems tbody td")
```

*Update*

I mistakenly assumed that it was the count of `<td>` elements that was desired because the `td` was in the selector. I should have paid more attention to the fact that the variable name used is called "rowCount". As stated by @Win in the comments, to select `<tr>` elements, the selector would be:

```
$("#tblItems tbody > tr")
```

The use of the child combinator (`>`) in this case is acceptable because all of the `<tr>` elements we want *will* be direct children of the `<tbody>`. But it is important to understand that it will work equally well without the `>` as long as there are no nested `<tr>`s in the `<tbody>`.

Comment: i try the both of these but the alert(rowCount) returns 6

Comment: @Teris2 if you want to count how many rows inside tbody , try above solution again , but this time count only TR ... `$("#tblItems tbody tr").length;`

Comment: @Teris2: Sorry I misunderstood which count you were after. I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: i want to set the row count to 1 without using rowCount = 1;

Comment: @Teris2: Understood. The updated selector I posted - `$("#tblItems tbody > tr")` - will return the number of `<tr>` elements that are direct children of the `<tbody>`. As long as you have a single `<tr>`, this number will be 1. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/fqkrwoca/